# How to update Query annotations with two-level parameters after upgrade to Spring-boot 2?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I cannot use complex 2-level parameters divided by dot character in mongodb requests from @Query annotation in spring-data-mongodb repositories after spring-boot version upgrade. What is the best approach here for spring-boot 2, and how I can fix it with minimal changes?

Problem appeared after upgrading spring-boot libraries from v.1.5.6.RELEASE to 2.1.5.RELEASE. Application starts succesfully, but errors appear on requests to mongodb in runtime.

```java
@Query("{_id.subscriberId: ?0}")
UserSubscription findOneBySubscriberId(String subscriberId);
```

I expect returning either UserSubscription object found or null value (like in spring-data-mongodb v.1.5.6). But on spring-data-mongodb v.2.1.5 I get error:
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 5. Character: '.'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `_id.subscriberId` is what you what to do here? Is your ID field a complex object? I think perhaps you intend to use something other than `_id`?

However you should be able to wrap the attribute in quotes to fix the error you are currently seeing:

```
@Query("{_`id.subscriberId`: ?0}")
```

Comment: sure it is a complex object and subscriberId is one of its internal fields

Comment: thanks, tried with quotes, next variant works well: `@Query(value = "{'_id.subscriberId': '?0'}")`